# Windows 10: Sleep mode don't work, the computer restart itself

Tags: windows, windows-10, power-supply, sleep

> Sleep mode is a low-power state designed to provide very fast resuming
>   of a computer's operation, with minimal power consumption.

But when I click on **`Windows > Power > Sleep`**, my computer normaly shut off, but then 2 seconds after entering in "Sleep mode" it restart itself every times.

I cannot get why and this is quite annoying.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @nmit026 Thank you for asking, unfortunately not, although I would have liked.

Answer (score 0):

If the battery health is ok then you should need to check your battery setting according to this protocol.
To fix this problem, open Settings > System and under Power & sleep settings click Additional power settings. From here, select Choose when to turn off the display. Select Restore default settings for this plan. If this option is not available or doesn't work, click Change advanced power settings.

Comment: Yes the battery health is ok,  I tried but unfortunately it didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be worth an answer, but I had this exact issue. In my case it was my printer. I turned it off, restarted my computer, and turned it on again. So make sure your peripheral hardware isn't interfering.

Answer (score 0):

Laptop computer will restart when is comes out of sleep mode on occasion. Windows 10.

I found on a Lenovo forum from a very smart user an answer for me. This however was re my Legion 15 Lenovo Ryzen laptop. New drivers and new graphic drivers did nothing. Win 10 updates and rollbacks (I have Macrium images) did nothing. Looking at Event log showed nothing.

So..... on that Lenovo Forum, I read that turning Bluetooth on if your computer has it solved the problem for them. I tried this and it solved it for me but we have the same Lenovo Legion model. The other solution was to enable the bios to accept a downgrade (older version). I did this and problem went away. So I could either turn on Bluetooth which I did not use or go back to a prior Lenovo Legion Bios version. So what would happen is this. I had laptop set to go to sleep. After about 3-6 resuming from sleep actions the laptop would not come out of sleep and would force a restart.